# Absolute value of a number in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How can the absolute number of a value be calculated in Clojure?

```
(abs  1) => 1
(abs -1) => 1
(abs  0) => 0
```

Answer (score 58):

As of Clojure 1.11, it is simply `(abs -1)` in both Clojure and Clojurescript.

In versions before, for double, float, long and int you can use the java.lang.Math method abs `(Math/abs -1)`

Take care it won't work for decimals, ratio's, bigint(eger)s and other Clojure numeric types. The official clojure contrib math library that tries guarantee working correctly with all of these is [clojure.math.numeric-tower](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower)

Comment: Also be aware that since Java methods are not first-class, they cannot be used as standalone arguments to functions. They must be wrapped in another function like `(map #(Math/abs %) coll)`, `(comp #(Math/abs %) -)` and so forth.

Comment: This also isn't platform independent (i.e. JVM vs ClojureScript), is it?

Comment: No, neither isn't. I guess it's time for a cljc version of numeric tower.

Comment: Note that as of today, `abs` in CLJS is not available yet - according to its docstring in the repo, it will arrive in CLJS `1.11.10`.

Answer (score 39):

you could always do

```
(defn abs [n] (max n (- n)))
```

Comment: (abs Long/MIN_VALUE), say hello to ArithmeticException

Comment: @SerCe, that is due to `-` function. if you want arbitrary precision you should use `-'` instead: `(defn abs [n] (max n (-' n)))`

Comment: @Shlomi No, it is due to the implementation choice in your function.  If you are creating an alternative to `Math/abs` that works with a broader range of Clojure types, you ought to utilize the `-'` function in your answer instead.

Answer (score 12):

The deprecated `clojure.contrib.math` provides an [`abs`](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure-contrib/math-api.html#clojure.contrib.math/abs) function.

The source is:

```
(defn abs "(abs n) is the absolute value of n" [n]
  (cond
   (not (number? n)) (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                             "abs requires a number"))
   (neg? n) (- n)
   :else n))
```

As @NielsK points out in the comments, [`clojure.math.numeric-tower`](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower) is the successor project.

Comment: Take care that all clojure .contrib. libraries have been deprecated for a long time. Examples using those libraries are old information. The name of the successor of clojure.contrib.math is clojure.math.numeric-tower, https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower

Comment: @NielsK, thanks, I've included that information in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`abs` is now available in the core clojure library since Clojure `1.11` release.

Docs for `abs` https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/abs

```
Usage: (abs a)

Returns the absolute value of a.
If a is Long/MIN_VALUE => Long/MIN_VALUE
If a is a double and zero => +0.0
If a is a double and ##Inf or ##-Inf => ##Inf
If a is a double and ##NaN => ##NaN

Added in Clojure version 1.11
```